# SQL: How to find Duplicate values in a large table

Tags: sql

I have a table of about 2 million SKU's.  Is there a way to detect any sku that occurs more than once by running a select query??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select SKU
From table
Group By SKU
Having Count(SKU) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT SKUColumn, COUNT(*) FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY SKUColumn HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select SKU, count(SKU) cnt from table group by SKU having cnt > 1
```

Comment: It will take an awful long time to look through that result set. . .

Comment: @Larry: agreed forgot to add having clause